# Find all primes $p$ such that $ 3x^2-1\equiv 0 \mod{p}$ has a solution

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

So I generally know how to do this for equations where $x^2$'s coefficient is $1$. Completing squares and then using quadratic reciprocity I can find that primes for which there are solutions depend on congruences modulo some number. But now I'm clueless on how to deal with that $3$.

Comment: Why does the $3$ change things?  Excluding $p=3$, this is the same as asking if $x^2 \equiv 3^{-1} \pmod p$ has a solution, which is the same as asking if $3$ is a square $\pmod p$.

Comment: $3$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if its multiplicative inverse modulo $p$ is a square modulo $p$.

Comment: @lulu yes, but I don't know if $3^-1$ is a prime or not (it depends on p), so I can't apply quadratic reciprocity (?), and in case I could, I'm clueless on computing $(p-1)(3^{-1}-1)/4$

Comment: Not following.  You said you knew how to handle the problem if the lead coefficient was $1$.  So suppose the problem was $x^2-3\equiv 0\pmod p$.  As discussed, other than a possible problem at $p=3$, this is equivalent to your problem.

Comment: To expand on what others have said - if $p\neq 3$ then multiply by $3$ to get $(3x)^2-3\equiv 0$ and set $3x=y$.

Comment: @MarkBennet thank you, that clarifies it :) I understand for $p=3$ it doesn't work because we multiply both sides by 0(?)

Comment: That is why @Lulu mentioned the possible problem at $p=3$ - indeed, that would be equivalent to multiplying by zero (equivalently you can't divide by $3$ mod $3$).  There tend to be these pesky exceptions where you have to be careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I post this, another answer claims that "there is no known law for all primes satisfying the question", and insinuates that it is impossible to say which primes will yield a solution.  This claim is incorrect. The problem yields to a standard application of Quadratic Reciprocity.

You want to find out for which primes the congruence
$$3x^2-1\equiv 0\pmod{p}$$
has a solution. The congruence clearly has a solution for $p=2$, and no solution for $p=3$, so we may assume that $p$ is odd and $p\gt 3$.

There are two ways to proceed here, both yielding the same conclusion: One, as Mark Bennet suggests, is multiplying through by $3$ (which is invertible modulo $p$). We then are looking at the congruence $9x^2\equiv 3\pmod{p}$, and since $9$ is a square, this has a solution if and only if $3$ is a square modulo $p$. So we want to find all odd primes $p$ for which $3$ is a quadratic residue.

Alternatively, we want to solve $3x^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. But since $3$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if its multiplicative inverse modulo $p$ is a square modulo $p$ (if $3\equiv g^2\pmod{p}$, then $3^{-1}\equiv 3^{p-2}\equiv (g^2)^{p-2} = (g^{p-2})^2\pmod{p}$, and conversely) then again we are reduced to finding the odd primes $p\gt 3$ for which $3$ is a quadratic residue.

By Quadratic Reciprocity, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) &= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) &\text{if }p\equiv 1\pmod{4},\\
-\left(\frac{p}{3}\right) &\text{if }p\equiv 3\pmod{4}
\end{array}\right. \\
&= \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &\text{if }p\equiv 1\pmod{4}\text{ and }p\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\
-1 &\text{if }p\equiv 1\pmod{4}\text{ and }p\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\
-1 &\text{if }p\equiv 3\pmod{4}\text{ and }p\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\
1 &\text{if }p\equiv 3\pmod{4}\text{ and }p\equiv 2\pmod{3}.
\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}$$
Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem this gives the complete description:
$$\left(\frac{3}{p}\right) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1  & \text{if } p\equiv 1, 11 \pmod{12}\\
-1 &\text{if } p\equiv 5, 7 \pmod{12}
\end{array}\right.$$

So your congruence has solutions if $p=2$, $p\equiv 1\pmod{12}$, or $p\equiv 11\pmod{12}$; and no solutions if $p=3$, $p\equiv 5\pmod{12}$, or $p\equiv 7\pmod{12}$.